# How to change program titlebar?

Tags: abap, titlebar, dynpro

I'm trying to show something else than the program title in the title bar but so far it's not working. I've tried:

```
SET TITLEBAR 'title001'.
```

When I double click `title001` I can create this object and save it but it still doesn't change the title. Do I have to activate it somewhere or is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that you call the `SET TITLEBAR` function in a module that is called from the `PBO` of your screen.
2. Make sure that `title001` is active.  You can check that by loading your module program in `SE80`, it should display everything that is used in the program in the tree to the right.